# Alternatives to Geiger Mueller tubes?

Tags: sensor

I'm using classical GM tubes for radiation measurement (gamma plus beta, natural radiation levels) and would like to know if there is a more "electronic" sensor for radiation.

Comment: Nothing is more purely electronic than electrons shooting through vacuum. :)

Comment: mmm, I have to admit you're right. I meant "more chip-like" :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of solid state/semiconductor approaches for ionizing radiation and they fall roughly into the following categories.

detectors with a conversion layer:
- XRay detectors: Image sensors with Gadox, NaI scinillators

Direct detectors:
- using Selenium, Germanium and Silicon

Indirect detectors:
- Using bolometric techniques, i.e. measuring heat increase in a material that causes a parametric shift like resistance.  VOx on bolometers, Thermopiles.  Can have issues with thermal (non-ionizing) radiation giving conflicting information.

In general though, because the work functions are higher lower energy ionizing radiation or that which has low penetration (beta) is harder to detect using these techniques.

Comment: direct detectors? what does silicon produce from gamma photons? charge? current? voltage? change in conductivity?

Comment: For Si specifically, above ~240 nm (Off the top of my head) you generate 2 electron/hole pairs or more for each photon incident.  I would look at what is done at CERN and what the LHC is using.

Comment: I will, thanks, although I think this we call altogether "radiation" comprises different particles, frequencies, energies and behaviours. My aim is to measure natural radioactivity, that surrounding us and coming from Earth's isotopes and cosmic radiation.

Comment: @Joan yes, it is incredibly broad, the semiconductor detectors will perform in a narrower niche but within that niche can have higher performance.  That said, come back and answer your own question when you find out more and find other detectors.

Answer (score 1):

I know MOSFETs and Si fotodiodes are used to detect radiation. In general, the larger the 'active' area, the better. IIRC BPW34 was used in some elektor circuits. Don't expect anything near the linearity and sensitivity of GM tubes.